# xyzForm; How to leave free the 2nd "column" of a "row" when using [halfWidth] on the 1st column

Tags: forms, serenity-platform

I would like to have an xyzForm.cs display some fields like this:

```
"Line 1" Dropdown                        (leave free)
"Line 2" Field1                          Field2
"Line 3" Field3                          Field4
```

My question is about the (leave free) part. Is there a declarative spacer or so which I could use to force Field1 down to the next line?

Currently I have to give the Dropdown full width until the end of Line 1 in order to bring Field1 down to Line 2.

With kind regards,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from @Victor Tomaili, I found the following solution:

If you want to shorten (in the width) a SF dropdown (jquery Select2), use the following code:

```
this.form.<your field>.element.parent().find(".select2-container").find(".select2-choice").addClass("<your CSS classname which contains the desired width either in px or %");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any declarative way. But you can write some css about use just half of line for line 1 dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

There is a declarative way too

```
public class OrderForm
{
    [HalfWidth(UntilNext = true), LabelWidth(130, UntilNext = true)]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    [FormCssClass("line-break-sm")]
    public DateTime RequiredDate { get; set; }
}
```

ref https://serenity.is/blog/2018/05/16/multi-column-layout#line-breaking